# Multiline write fails (Permission denied)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I would like to write a multiline string to a file that is only accessible with root permissions.

This is what I have so far:

```
sudo cat > /etc/init/myservice.conf <<EOL
start on runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

script

    cd ~/somefolder

    . venv/bin/activate

    exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

end script
EOL
```

When this command, all I get is "Permission Denied". Creating the file manually works.

Comment: Related: [Redirecting Output in the Shell Permissions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68068/redirecting-output-in-the-shell-permissions)

Comment: Also note that given your snippet, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out that sudo doesn't affect redirections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output redirection is processed *before* `sudo` runs, so you are still trying to open the file as yourself, not as root. One option is to use `tee` instead of `cat`, since `tee`, rather than the current shell, will open the file for writing.

```
sudo tee /etc/init/myservice.conf > /dev/null <<EOF
start on runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

script

  cd ~/somefolder

  . venv/bin/activate

  exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

end script
EOF
```

While the delimiter used doesn't really matter, it makes more sense to use something that indicates end of *file*, rather than end of *line* :) `tee` actually writes its input to both the named file(s) and standard output, but you don't need to see what you are writing, hence the redirection to `/dev/null`.